# Error when adding a reference to my unit test project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

From my newly created Test project, I try to add a reference to my actual project. like this:
*In Solution Explorer, select References in the BankTests project and then choose Add Reference... from the context menu.*

I get an error saying 'Unable to add a reference to project 'MyProject'.

Comment: Right click on Reference, add reference, click on solution, select the project

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your project settings, change your Target Framework from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4". That should do it.

Comment: That was my problem. I tried to create a unit test project for Windows Phone 8.1 and I used a class library project for desktop. They aren't compatible, so I had to add a `Unit Test App (Windows Phone)` project.

Comment: Same here @Tonatio it was because I added a normal C# Unit Test but you have to add the one for Windows Phone as you said :) Thanks. VS 2015 community here on Windows 10

Answer (score 9):

Check your target Framework in both project settings. It should be the same.

Comment: I had increased my target framework to 4.5.2 and never did it for my test project. This fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem, tried all solutions listed here but unable to add. with your answer i changed framework of both target source projects, it started working...